# How to add rows to a table based on a condition?

Tags: r, dax

I would like to create a table in which I can give access to a certain page of a report for a certain user

Imagine I have a table like this:
[image]

I have another table in which I have the name of every report page:
[image]

I want to get a table in which I have the users and all the pages at which they hace access to depending on their group. Group 1 can see all pages, but group 2 only can see the Team page:

[image]

The best option would be doing it in DAX code but I think it could be easier doing it using R. Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you mention DAX I guess you are using some Excel or Power BI? Since it is more integrated then R, why not just use Power Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tidyverse` package gives you easy tools to manipulate dataframes. You can create 3 variables (Orders, Sales, Team) recording the access rights for each page (with 1 or 0 for example) using `case_when` with a condition on Group, and then `pivot_longer` on these variables, and finally only keep rows where there is an access right with `filter`.

```
library(tidyverse)
Group <- c(1,2,1,2,2)
User <- c("alex","pablo","carlos","pepe","paula") %>% paste0("@gmail.com")
df <- data.frame(Group, User)

df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(Orders = case_when(Group==1 ~ 1,  
                            Group==2 ~ 0),
         Sales = Orders,
         Team = 1) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(Orders, Sales, Team), names_to = "Page") %>% 
  filter(value == 1) %>% 
  select(-value)
```

Output

```
> df
  Group             User
1     1   alex@gmail.com
2     2  pablo@gmail.com
3     1 carlos@gmail.com
4     2   pepe@gmail.com
5     2  paula@gmail.com
> df2
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  Group User             Page  
  <dbl> <chr>            <chr> 
1     1 alex@gmail.com   Orders
2     1 alex@gmail.com   Sales 
3     1 alex@gmail.com   Team  
4     2 pablo@gmail.com  Team  
5     1 carlos@gmail.com Orders
6     1 carlos@gmail.com Sales 
7     1 carlos@gmail.com Team  
8     2 pepe@gmail.com   Team  
9     2 paula@gmail.com  Team
```

Answer (score 1):

An idea can be,

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
 mutate(page = toString(df1$page_name)) %>% 
 separate_rows(page, sep = ', ') %>% 
 mutate(page = replace(page, Group == 2 & page != 'team', NA)) %>% 
 na.omit()

# A tibble: 9 x 3
  Group User  page  
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> 
1     1 A     orders
2     1 A     sales 
3     1 A     team  
4     2 B     team  
5     1 C     orders
6     1 C     sales 
7     1 C     team  
8     2 D     team  
9     2 E     team
```

**DATA**

```
dput(df)
structure(list(Group = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 2), User = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D", "E")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

dput(df1)
structure(list(page_name = c("orders", "sales", "team")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another idea using `fuzzyjoin` package:

## Data

```
users <- data.frame(
  Group = c("1","2","1","2","2"),
  User = c("alex","pablo","carlos","pepe","paula")
)

  Group   User
1     1   alex
2     2  pablo
3     1 carlos
4     2   pepe
5     2  paula
```

You can then add a column to the Page dataframe which tell the groups allowed to have access to each category:

```
pagename <- data.frame(
  Page = c("Order","Sales","Team"),
  Allowed = c("1","1","1|2")
)

   Page Allowed
1 Order       1
2 Sales       1
3  Team     1|2
```

And finally using `fuzzyjoin::regex_left_join`:

```
users |> 
  fuzzyjoin::regex_left_join(pagename,
                             by = c(Group = "Allowed")) |> 
  dplyr::select(-Allowed)
```

## Output

```
  Group   User  Page
1     1   alex Order
2     1   alex Sales
3     1   alex  Team
4     2  pablo  Team
5     1 carlos Order
6     1 carlos Sales
7     1 carlos  Team
8     2   pepe  Team
9     2  paula  Team
```